# jQuery AJAX to get Vimeo thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong here? the youtube one is working but its not adding the image from thevideoThumbV function and cant work out why...

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yurt5bb6/3/

function:

```
function videoThumbV(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '//vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + id + '.json',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            var thumbnail_src = data[0].thumbnail_large;
            return '<img class="vimeo-thumb" src="' + thumbnail_src + '"><div class="play-button"></div>';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return stuff from synchronous call, you need to use a callback:

```
function videoThumbV(id, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '//vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + id + '.json',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            var thumbnail_src = data[0].thumbnail_large;
            callback('<img class="vimeo-thumb" src="' + thumbnail_src + '"><div class="play-button"></div>');
        }
    });
}

videoThumbV(id, function(str) {
    player.html(str);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yurt5bb6/4/)**

Comment: Thanks mate, makes sense :)